# I am creating TestNG.xml in my selenium script but on creating the same, this is how its showing how to get it in right format?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng, testng.xml

[This is how its showing which is not correct xml format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysVHx.png)

I searched for a solution but can't find one on how to solve this.
I am selecting the option of convert to TestNG.xml, the runner folder that I am selecting to add the file is not showing in xml format but something like in the image.

I am using maven for dependency management and have already installed the TestNG plugin in eclipse and in POM.xml as well.

Comment: Look at the bottom of the editor and you'll see the tabs to flip between Design and Source.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the two different modes at the bottom:

- ***Design***
- ***Source***

You are in ***Design*** mode, hence you see the design.

Click on ***Source*** option to flip to the other mode.